# WPF Progress bar update as list of items run

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like some help implementing a progress bar in my WPF application (MVVM).

My MainWindow has a button that runs this method:

```
private void AnalysisClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    model.RunAnalysis();
}
```

My model runs a list of items thru a separate engine class:

```
foreach(List<Item> item in items)
    allItemResults.Add(engine.RunItem(item));
```

The `RunItem` method will then run that item.

My question is: How can I have each item update a `ProgressBar` in my MainWindow as it finishes?

EDIT: This is .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the following blog.. you can easily achieve this using the sample code...

http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html

Comment: I'm working with .NET 3.5 which does not have `TaskFactory`. Sorry, I'll update my post to mention that.